# Create categories through installer

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to use below script to create a set of categories. The script works fine but I have an issue and I am wondering if their is an option to set the ID for a new category?

Problem is that I am not able to add a sub category for a category that is not in the database yet. I do not know the ID of that category yet because it's in the same import as the new sub category.. Hope this makes sense

```
    setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $count = 0;

    $file = fopen('./var/import/import_cat.csv', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) { $count++;
      //$line is an array of the csv elements

      if (!empty($line[0]) && !empty($line[1])) { 

          $data['general']['path'] = $line[0];
          $data['general']['name'] = $line[1];
          $data['general']['meta_title'] = "";
          $data['general']['meta_description'] = $line[5];
          $data['general']['is_active'] = $line[2];
          $data['general']['url_key'] = "";
          $data['general']['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS";
          $data['general']['is_anchor'] = 0;
          $data['general']['navigation_description'] = $line[3];
          $data['general']['is_primary_category'] = $line[4];

          $data['category']['parent'] = $line[0]; // 3 top level
          $storeId = 0;

          createCategory($data,$storeId);
          sleep(0.5);
          unset($data);
        }

    }  


     function createCategory($data,$storeId) {

    echo "Starting {$data['general']['name']} [{$data['category']['parent']}] ...";

      $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
      $category->setStoreId($storeId);

      # Fix must be applied to run script
      #http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/appserv/main.php/viewreply/157328/

          if (is_array($data)) {
              $category->addData($data['general']);

              if (!$category->getId()) {

                  $parentId = $data['category']['parent'];
                  if (!$parentId) {
                      if ($storeId) {
                          $parentId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
                      }
                      else {
                          $parentId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
                      }
                  }
                  $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
                  $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());

              }

                    /**
                     * Check "Use Default Value" checkboxes values
                     */
                    if ($useDefaults = $data['use_default']) {
                        foreach ($useDefaults as $attributeCode) {
                            $category->setData($attributeCode, null);
                        }
                    }             

              $category->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());

              if (isset($data['category_products']) &&
                  !$category->getProductsReadonly()) {
                  $products = array();
                  parse_str($data['category_products'], $products);
                  $category->setPostedProducts($products);
              }

              try {
                  $category->save();
                  echo "Suceeded 
 ";
              }
              catch (Exception $e){
                    echo "Failed 
";

              }
          }     

  }
```

Comment: Hi Sander, did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

With this information you would think that the solution would be something like :

```
$this->startSetup();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setPath('1/2') // set parent to be root category
    ->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
    ->setName('Category Name')
    ...
    ->save();
$this->endSetup();
```

But this code doesn't work either. Indeed after looking into Mage::app() (Mage_Core_Model_App Line 804) I noticed a IF condition that would always return the default store if you're in a setup script.

The trick is to fake that you're not in a setup script, my working solution is:

```
$this->startSetup();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

// Force the store to be admin
Mage::app()->setUpdateMode(false);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setPath('1/2') // set parent to be root category
    ->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
    ->setName('Category Name')
    ...
    ->save();
$this->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have defined the "parent" in your CSV file somehow. I see that position `0` would contain a "path". You should keep track of a mapping of the inserted ID's of all categories to their "path".

Lets say your path for a third level category ("Sub Sub Category") is defined like this:

```
"Main Category/Sub Category"
```

After `$category->save();` you should get the category's ID:

```
try {
    $category->save();

    echo "Suceeded (ID: " . $category->getId() . ")\n";

    $path = explode('/', $data['general']['path']);
    $path[] = $data['general']['name']; // Add the current category to the path
    $path = implode('/', $path);
    $catPathIdMapping[$path] = $category->getId();
} catch...
```

Then when creating another category, to look up the parent ID:

```
$parentId = $catPathIdMapping[ $data['general']['path'] ];
```

At the end your mapping would look like:

```
array (
  'Main Category A' => 1,
  'Main Category A/Sub Category A' => 2,
  'Main Category A/Sub Category A/Sub Sub Category A' => 3,
  'Main Category A/Sub Category A/Sub Sub Category B' => 4,
  'Main Category A/Sub Category A/Sub Sub Category C' => 5,
  'Main Category A/Sub Category B' => 6,
  'Main Category A/Sub Category B/Sub Sub Category A' => 7,
  'Main Category A/Sub Category B/Sub Sub Category B' => 8,
  'Main Category B' => 9,
  'Main Category B/Sub Category A' => 10,
)
```